# for loop isn't adding 1 each time it loops

Tags: java, for-loop, try-catch

I'm really sorry if this is a dumb question, I just need someone else's perspective. I have this code in which I'm printing to the output stream in a client to a server. for some reason the for loop isn't adding 1 to i each time it loops. Whenever I run it I get:

`threads[i]: Thread[Thread-2,5,main] threads[i].clientName: Bill maxClientsCount: 15 i: 0
threads[i]: Thread[Thread-2,5,main] threads[i].clientName: Bill maxClientsCount: 15 i: 0`

but it only prints it out twice. Whenever I type something in the client, the for loop runs again with `i` being 1. So what I'm getting out of this is that the for loop waits until the if loop has finished running until it runs again. This shouldn't be the case though because it should only check if restart isn't equal to `""`, then move on to the for loop. I'm sorry in advance if someone already asked this question, I already tried looking for this question, but was not successful. One detail you should keep in mind is that the catch doesn't catch anything until a client closes the window.

**Here is the code:**

```
while (true) {
    restart = clientIn;
    if (!restart.equals("")) {
        break;
    }
    int j = 0;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
            System.out.println("threads[i]: " + threads[i] + "threads[i].clientName: "
                            + threads[i].clientName + "maxClientsCount: " + maxClientsCount + "i: " + i);
            if (threads[i] != null && threads[i].clientName != null) {
                j = i + 1;
                System.out.println(threads[i].is.readLine());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("broke");
```

Comment: What is the size of maxClientsCount ?

Comment: I am guessing the while loop is running twice and the for loop is running only once  as maxClientsCount is 1 and only one iteration is possible.

Comment: @EyadMhanna 15. I checked that too :(

Comment: Maybe you have two objects

Comment: @humblefoolish could you elaborate? i already checked the value of maxClientsCount and its 15.

Comment: @user7 what do you mean by that?

Comment: Please give us a [mcve].

Comment: @Th1sguy26 Are you sure there are no exceptions happening? Maybe threads array is null or not initialized because your code is alright the only way it could break if that it throws an exception

Comment: do a sysout after the for loop to check if it exited the loop or if it's stuck somewhere in the loop. Use a debugger or sysout on each line and you'll figure out the issue.

Comment: @Th1sguy26 I was guessing that the maxClientsCount is  1 as that will be the only possible scenario of getting `i: 0` twice. Is maxClientsCount changing somewhere in your code or is it a constant?

Comment: What is the value of restart

Comment: also catch all Exceptions catch (Exception e) {and print something here}

Comment: @EyadMhanna check the edited code, I added new syso's for stuff that I have tried. :)

Comment: @isaace check the edited code, I added new syso's for stuff that I have tried. :)

Comment: @Totoro it is whatever the client inputs

Comment: @Th1sguy26 I checked but you didn't write what the output was

Comment: @EyadMhanna didn't expect such a fast response sorry, it's updated now.

Comment: @Th1sguy26 one more step is to catch all exception not just IO exception so in your catch line please write catch (Exception e) then print the stacktrace of e like e.printstacktrace()

Comment: @EyadMhanna will do! just a sec.

Comment: @EyadMhanna okay, it's done. I also added at the end an explanation as to when the catch statement comes into play.

Comment: @isaace i added the Exception e and printStackTrace and gave an explanation as to when the catch statement comes into play. Thank you for your patience

Comment: @Th1sguy26 In the first line of the for loop, you print out the details for a thread before checking that it is not null. If there is a null element, you'll get a null pointer exception that isn't caught because you're only catching IOExceptions. This wouldn't explain why it prints out the first object twice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, I had two clients connected to the server which is why the syso was printing out two lines. as soon as I realized that the two clients were connected to the server, I realized all I needed to do was check if `this` thread was still connected, as you can see below:

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this) {
            while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < 1000) {
                if (threads[i].is.read() == -1) {
                    MyClientSocket.input("");
                }
            }
        }                   
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    break;
}
```

The reason I inlcuded the `MyClientSocket.input("");` is because I needed it to break out of all the loops so i just sent it to the catch method. Another thing I included was the method where it detects if you say yes, no, or undefined, which you can see below:

```
restart = clientIn;
if (restart.contains("yes")) {
    run();
} else if (restart.contains("no")) {
    break;
} else if (!restart.equals("")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
        if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this) {
            threads[i].os.println("Sorry I couldn't understand you. Please say yes or no.");
        }
    }
}
```

The last for loop just sends the message to every client that's connected to the server.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found out the problem in your code, you're reading client input each time and firing the for loop each time the user enters something but your if clause at the first line after the while is wrong, you're breaking the while loop if user enters anything other than "" like this:

```
if (!restart.equals("")) {
        break;
    }
```

What you should do is break the loop if the user enters nothing like the following:

```
if (restart.equals("")) {
            break;
        }
```

Please test it from your side and tell if it works.

Comment: This wouldn't work either because that's the catcher to see if the user types something into the server, then he is still there, and so it doesn't need to check if the user has exited without saying "/quit" I could change it to if (!restart.equals(null))

Comment: Ok! I made a breakthrough! Check my edited question!

Answer (score 1):

Try catching a throwable after you catch the IOException. Potentially you aren't getting an IOException. You can log in that catch block as well and throw the throwable on again if need be

You are printing a value for 'threads[i].clientName' but then check if 'threads[i]' is null, so perhaps a null pointer exception is going on here?

Edit:
To catch a throwable as well, just add this to you code:

```
...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        System.out.println("I have some other problem: " + t.getMessage());
        t.printStackTrace();
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("broke");
```

Comment: it's not giving me any type of error, and it's printing out threads[i] as shown in my queston. Could you elaborate on your first response though?

Comment: If your code throws something other than an IOException, you won't see anything in your log because that is all you are catching. If you use 'Throwable' you are making sure that you log any error thrown - that's a situation that's caught me out plenty before

Comment: If your second entry in the array is null, then your println will throw a NullPointerException when it attempts to resolve 'threads[i].clientName'. As to why you get the line printed twice, I can only presume you enter the loop twice. Nothing in the code looks like it should do that

Comment: I figured one little thing out, it wasn't throwing a NullPointerException because of a declaration i made at the beginning of the class. It's printing out the message twice because there are two clients connected to the server and so there are two threads printing out individual information. I go into more detail with this in my answer that i made to my own question. Although I would like to know how to make something throwable; it could make my life easier!

Comment: Also, check my new answer, just now added it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the maxClientsCount is equal to 1, so the for loop only executes once.  The While loop is never set to false so it keeps executing the for loop making it look like it is not incrementing.

Comment: He said in the comment that it's 15 -_-